# What is this bell-shaped, cast iron plumbing part?

Tags: plumbing

I have old galvanized steel plumbing. What exactly is this pictured part called and what's its function? This is cold water and leads to a faucet of a utility sink.

[image: part]

Comment: It's probably an anti-hammer air chamber. Is there just the one connection?

Comment: Yes, off the tee to the bell shaped thing there is just one connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably an anti-hammer air chamber, although I can't seem to find any photos of similar devices from the era to confirm this. Its purpose is to absorb shock from *[fluid hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_hammer)*, caused by momentum in the water stream, which can cause result in annoying banging noise and, potentially, damage to the plumbing or connected fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

Also commonly known as a "pressure reducing valve".  The one pictured looks quite old though.

Comment: This does indeed resemble a PRV, but with only one connection it can't be